# Isolate scope for functions does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive for a tab view. It does not work when I try to isolate the scope. Why might it be?

Currently scope part is commented out and works fine.

When I isolate the scope, it wouldn't call the function loadTab()

```
myApp.directive("tabsPanel", () => {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        // scope: {
        //     tabs: "=tabs",
        //     activeTab: "=",
        //     loadTab: "&"
        // },
        transclude: true,
        link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
            console.log(scope);
        },
        templateUrl: "views/tabs-panel.html"
    }
});
```

What it shows in the console.log when I isolate the scope:

```
activeTab: undefined
loadTab: (locals)
tabs: Array[4]
```

- activeTab can be undefined, it is expected

templateUrl:

```
<div class="tabs-panel">
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
        <ul class="tabs-nav">
            <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
                <a href class="tablinks" ng-bind="::tab.name" ng-click="loadTab({currentTab: tab})" ng-class="{'selected-tab' : activeTab === tab}"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <match-history-tab ng-show="activeTab.url === 'history'"></match-history-tab>
        <odd-movements-tab ng-show="activeTab.url === 'odds'"></odd-movements-tab>
        <injuries-and-suspensions-tab ng-show="activeTab.url === 'injury'"></injuries-and-suspensions-tab>
        <week-stats-tab ng-show="activeTab.url === 'general'"></week-stats-tab>
    </div>
</div>
```

The HTML that uses tabs-panel:

```
<div class="main-panel">
    <tabs-panel tabs="tabs"></tabs-panel>
</div>
```

The called function:

```
$scope.loadTab = (selectedTab) => {
    if(selectedTab) {
        activeTab = selectedTab.currentTab;
    } else {
        $scope.activeTab = $scope.tabs[0];
    }
};
```

Comment: Should it be $scope.activeTab in the first if statement?

Comment: And the HTML that uses `tabsPanel`?

Comment: @zeroflagL added now

Comment: @rrd No it is checking if selectedTab is undefined. If it is undefined it will just load the first tab.

Comment: `<tabs-panel tabs="tabs">` - > Where is `load-tab=""`?

Comment: @zeroflagL in the controller

Comment: The HTML needs a `load-tab` attribute, otherwise `loadTab: "&"`makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at the below example snippet , how to call function from isolated scope.
you are not assigning function to isolated scope variable (load-tab)

like this

```
 <tabs-panel load-tab="loadTab(data)"></tabs-panel>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);

app.directive("tabsPanel", () => {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
         scope: {
             tabs: "=tabs",
             activeTab: "=",
             loadTab: "&"
         },
        transclude: true,
        link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
           
        },
        template: "<h2 ng-click='loadTab({data:\"world\"})'>click here</h2>"
    }
});

app.controller('todoCtrl',function($scope){

  $scope.loadTab = function(data){
   alert("hello " +data);
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
   
  <div ng-controller="todoCtrl">
    <tabs-panel load-tab="loadTab(data)"></tabs-panel>
   </div>
 </div>
```